# Exclude multiple page templates

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, wordpress-theming

I need to exclude a child theme function from certain page templates.

I can exclude one template like this

```
if (!(is_page_template( 'templates/my_page_template.php' )))
{ // the child theme function here
 ....
}
```

How do I add more page templates to exclude statement?

Comment: if( !is_page_template( 'templates/my_page_template.php' ) && !is_page_template( 'templates/my_page_template2.php' ) ){}

Comment: just add the extra condition - Or if you have several, create a switch statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (
    !(
    (is_page_template( 'templates/my_page_template.php' ))   or 
    (is_page_template( 'templates/my_page_template1.php' ))   or 
    (is_page_template( 'templates/my_page_template2.php' ))   or 
    (is_page_template( 'templates/my_page_template3.php' ))   or 
    )

)
{ // the child theme function here
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The is_page_template function accepts an array as argument. See here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/

You can do something like:

```
if ( ! ( is_page_template( array('templates/my_page_template.php', 'templates/my_page_template2.php') ) ) )
{ // the child theme function here
  ....
}
```